# Structuring Multiple Enemy Game Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is the ideal way to structure multiple game objects of the same type, all can be controlled using a single controller, but having different concrete function? I don't want to do a switch everything I want to change the Animations.

For example, a man can `Walk()` and `Run()`, a dog can `Crawl()`, and a bat can `Fly()`. But all of them are Enemy and they have Heath and they all moved with Nav Mesh Agent.

And in my Main game I am doing something like this:

```
enemy.SetDestination(pos);
```

Comment: Why can't you name the animations in the same way? Such as Move (for Walking or moving), PersonalAction (for crawling, flying or running).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to you use Interfaces. In C# it allows to create functions and properties that will be common in multiple types of objects.

In order to create an interface you must use "interface" reserved word:

```
public interface InterfaceName {

    //Properties of the interface
    int health {get; set;}

    //Methods of the interface
    void Hit(int damage);
}
```

Interfaces are very similar to classes but it will not have definitions in its methods. They are use to struct similar behaviors. Once you have create your interface, in your main class you need to implement it:

```
public class YourClass : InterfaceName {
   //.....

   // Implementation of your interface
   void Hit(int damage){
      //Your code here
   }

   //.....
}
```

Since C# does not support multiple inheritance of classes, interfaces are very important in order to reuse code.

If you need more info about interfaces, I recommend to you this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173156.aspx)

**EDIT :**

have a look at this as well : [Unity - Interfaces](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/interfaces)